# How do I insert records with new date (Date + 5 days) for a given record ID in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have table of named "Tests" with Test_ID, Test_Date, Test_Name and Done? (y/n) fields.

There are 5 tests in a month on 5 different dates.  Once a test is done, user clicks on Done? field and selects Yes or No.

Once the user selects "Yes", I want a new record to be added to the table "Tests" with the same value of Test_Name but the Test_Date should be Test_Date + 5 days.

I tried Append query but it adds 5 days to all the previous records and thus the Test_Date and Test_Name are repeated each time the query is run.

I tried "Insert Into" statement on "After Update" property of "Done?" field on the form, but it gives error message.

Please can anyone help?

The following is the statement I tried:

```
Private Sub Done__AfterUpdate()
    Insert Into Tests ([Test_Name], [Test_Date], Values ([Test_Name], ([Test_Date] + 5))

End Sub
```

It gives the compile error:

> Expected: End of Statement

```
    |  Test_ID  |  Test_Name  |  Test_Date  |    Done?   |
    ------------------------------------------------------
    |     1     |    Test 1   | 01/01/2017  |     Yes    |
    |     2     |    Test 2   | 02/01/2017  |            |
```

Comment: Please -->[edit]<-- your question and include the sql statements you tried as well as sample data and the expected result to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Looks like you just need to fix `...[Test_Date], Values ...` to `...[Test_Date]) Values ...` - a closing `)` instead of `,` after your column names.

Comment: Even with _____Private Sub Done__AfterUpdate()
Insert Into Tests ([Test_Name], [Test_Date]) Values ([Test_Name], ([Test_Date] + 5))
End Sub___, it is still showing the compile error saying Expected: End of Statement and the table name in the Sub is highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run SQL directly in VBA. So:

```
Private Sub Done__AfterUpdate()

    Dim Sql      As String
    Dim TestName As String
    Dim TestDate As Date

    TestName = Me![Test Name].Value
    TestDate = DateAdd("d", 5, Me![Test Date].Value)

    Sql = "Insert Into Tests ([Test_Name], [Test_Date]) Values ('" & TestName & "',#" & Format(TestDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#)"
    CurrentDb.Execute Sql

End Sub
```

Comment: That is brilliant. Worked just fine for me. Thanks a lot Gustav.  This will help me schedule all tests done in my lab and miss not even one. Best regards.

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered. Have a nice weekend.